# Convert class to its values while calling from Array.from(classObj)

Tags: javascript

I have a class , I want whenever i called `Array.from(myclassObj)` it should return the elements of class.

```js
class HelloWorld { 
  
    constructor() { 
        this.element = [1,2,3]; 
    } 
}
var helloObject = new HelloWorld();
console.log(helloObject);

var elements = Array.from(helloObject);
console.log(elements);
//should return [1,2,3] but returning []
```

How can I achieve this, Not getting any idea about this.

What property needs to be defined inside `Class` so that, it should return the elements instead.

Comment: `Array.from(helloObject.element)` rather than passing full class object, just pass the property

Comment: @MUHAMMADILYAS agree that works, but i need to create a generic output. Without using the element, and need to keep element private.

Comment: Can't you then call a generic method which answers those fields you want to be selected from the class?  This way fields are private and each different class (if you want to keep generic, I guess it's because you have more classes definition) has its own result? Something like.. a method getElements

Comment: @AndD restricted to call any method. `Array.from(helloObject);` this should return the array present in `element` property of class. I'm checking if there is any generic method/ attribute which get referred when we pass obj to `Array.from`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make your class `iterable` and than you will be able to use `Array.from()` on it.

> The Array.from() static method creates a new, shallow-copied Array
> instance from an array-like or **iterable** object. [(from here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
class HelloWorld { 
  
    constructor() { 
        this.element = [1,2,3]; 
        this.length= this.element.length;
    }
    *[Symbol.iterator] () {
            
             yield* this.element;
       }
  
}
var helloObject = new HelloWorld();
console.log(helloObject);

var elements = Array.from(helloObject);
console.log(elements);
```